# Erros no programa para classificar um triângulo

Tags: python, matemática, triângulo

Estou com alguns problemas e não sei como corrigir:

1) Um triângulo equilátero, três lados iguais e ângulos = 60°, é lido como um triângulo isósceles (dois lados iguais).

2) Além de imprimir errado, eu não consigo retirar esse 'NONE'.

3) Quando o triângulo tem um dos ângulos = 90, ele é retângulo. Mas o programa não reconhece.

4) O quarto e último problema é que eu não sei como posso reiniciar o programa:
'Digite S para reiniciar ou N para finalizar o programa'

Alguém pode me ajudar ???

```
import math


# lado a 
a = int(input('Digite o valor de um dos lados do triângulo '))

# lado b
b = int(input('Digite o valor do outro lado do triângulo '))

# angulo entre a e b
m = int(input('Digite o ângulo entre estes dois lados '))
ab = (m*math.pi)/180

# calculo do lado c
def lado_c ():
    global a,b,c,ab
    c = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b*math.cos(ab))
    return round(c,2)

# angulo entre a e c
def angulo_ac ():
    global a,b,c,ac
    n = ((a**2+c**2)-(b**2))/(2*a*c)
    ac = (math.acos(n)*180)/math.pi 
    return (round(ac,2))

# angulo b e c
def angulo_bc ():
    global a,b,c,bc
    p = ((c**2+b**2)-(a**2))/(2*b*c)
    bc =(math.acos(p)*180)/math.pi
    return (round(bc,2))

# perímetro
def perimetro ():
    global P,a,b,c
    P =(a+b+c)
    return P

# área
def area ():
    global a,b,c,P,A
    p = (a+b+c)/2
    A = float(math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))
    return A

# altura
def altura ():
    global A
    h = (A*2)/c
    return h

# classificação quanto aos lados
def lado_class ():
    global a,b,c,ab
    if a!=b and a!=c and b!=c:
        print ('Escaleno')
    elif ab == 60 and a == b and b == c:
        print ('Equilátero')
    elif a != b and b == c or b !=c and c == a or c !=a and a==b:
        print ('Isósceles')
    return

# classificação quanto aos angulos
def angulo_class ():
    global ab, ac, bc            
    if ab == 90 or bc == 90 or ac == 90:
        print ('Retângulo')
    elif ab < 90 and bc < 90 and ac < 90:
        print ('Acutângulo')
    elif ab > 90 and bc < 90 and ac < 90   or   bc > 90 and ac < 90 and ab < 90    or   ac > 90 and ac < 90 and ab < 90 :
        print ('Obtusângulo')
    return 

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print ('Lado c = '+ str(round(lado_c (),2)))

print ('Ângulo entre a e c '+str(angulo_ac ()))
print ('Ângulo entre b e c '+str(angulo_bc ()))
print('Área = '+str(round(area (),2))+' unidades de área')
print('Perímetro = '+str(round(perimetro(),2))+' unidades de comprimento')
print ('Altura, em relação ao lado c = '+str(round(altura (),2))+' unidades de comprimento')
print(lado_class ())
print (angulo_class ())

> import math

# lado a 
a = int(input('Digite o valor de um dos lados do triângulo '))

# lado b
b = int(input('Digite o valor do outro lado do triângulo '))

# angulo entre a e b
m = int(input('Digite o ângulo entre estes dois lados '))
ab = (m*math.pi)/180

# calculo do lado c
def lado_c ():
    global a,b,c,ab
    c = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b*math.cos(ab))
    return round(c,2)

# angulo entre a e c
def angulo_ac ():
    global a,b,c,ac
    n = ((a**2+c**2)-(b**2))/(2*a*c)
    ac = (math.acos(n)*180)/math.pi 
    return (round(ac,2))

# angulo b e c
def angulo_bc ():
    global a,b,c,bc
    p = ((c**2+b**2)-(a**2))/(2*b*c)
    bc =(math.acos(p)*180)/math.pi
    return (round(bc,2))

# perímetro
def perimetro ():
    global P,a,b,c
    P =(a+b+c)
    return P

# área
def area ():
    global a,b,c,P,A
    p = (a+b+c)/2
    A = float(math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))
    return A

# altura
def altura ():
    global A
    h = (A*2)/c
    return h

# classificação quanto aos lados
def lado_class ():
    global a,b,c,ab
    if a!=b and a!=c and b!=c:
        print ('Escaleno')
    elif ab == 60 and a == b and b == c:
        print ('Equilátero')
    elif a != b and b == c or b !=c and c == a or c !=a and a==b:
        print ('Isósceles')
    return

# classificação quanto aos angulos
def angulo_class ():
    global ab, ac, bc            
    if ab == 90 or bc == 90 or ac == 90:
        print ('Retângulo')
    elif ab < 90 and bc < 90 and ac < 90:
        print ('Acutângulo')
    elif ab > 90 and bc < 90 and ac < 90   or   bc > 90 and ac < 90 and ab < 90    or   ac > 90 and ac < 90 and ab < 90 :
        print ('Obtusângulo')
    return 

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print ('Lado c = '+ str(round(lado_c (),2)))

print ('Ângulo entre a e c '+str(angulo_ac ()))
print ('Ângulo entre b e c '+str(angulo_bc ()))
print('Área = '+str(round(area (),2))+' unidades de área')
print('Perímetro = '+str(round(perimetro(),2))+' unidades de comprimento')
print ('Altura, em relação ao lado c = '+str(round(altura (),2))+' unidades de comprimento')
print(lado_class ())
print (angulo_class ())
```

Eu também publiquei o código aqui (é melhor para visualizar):
https://code.sololearn.com/cUh4dY3oul2A/#py

Comment: Antes de mais nada, faça o [tour] para aprender usar o site.

Comment: Por quê parece ter o código duplicado na pergunta? Você colou duas vezes ou são diferentes?

Comment: @Raphael , no ítem 1, se um triangulo tem dois lados iguais e tem 60 graus entre eles, você pode garantir que é equilátero. Então, o if poderia ser ```ab == 60 and a == b```.

Comment: @Raphael, o NONE é porque está imprimindo o return vazio.

Answer (score 1):

As **questões 1 e 3** podem ser respondidas com a análise de suas variáveis e dos retornos das suas funções. Em um exemplo em que defino um dos lados do triangulo como 50, outro lado como 50 e o ângulo entre eles de 60°, vou obter como resposta do seu script:

```
a: 50                         # Valor do lado a - int
b: 50                         # Valor do lado b - int
c: 49.99999999999999          # Valor do lado c não arredondado
m: 60                         # Ângulo ab (graus) - int
ab: 1.0471975511965976        # Ângulo ab (radianos) não arredondado
ac: 60.00000000000001         # Ângulo ac (graus) não arredondado
bc: 60.00000000000001         # Ângulo bc (graus) não arredondado
lado_c: 50.0                  # Valor do lado c arredondado ---- Retorno de função
angulo_ac: 60.0               # Ângulo ac (graus) arredondado ---- Retorno de função
angulo_bc: 60.0               # Ângulo bc (graus) arredondado ---- Retorno de função
```

A partir desses dados é possível ver o porquê das suas funções retornarem com alguns erros. Ao analisar a função lado_class() temos:

```
def lado_class ():
    global a,b,c,ab
    if a != b and a != c and b != c:
    """ Comparação a, b e c.
        Sua variável c não está arredondada, o que vai influenciar na sua comparação.
    """
        print ('Escaleno')
    elif ab == 60 and a == b and b == c:
    """ Comparação a, b e c + análise do ângulo ab.
        Novamente sua variável c não está arredondada.
        A variável ab está definida como o ângulo entre a e b em RADIANOS,
        porém você compara ela com o valor em graus.
    """
        print ('Equilátero')
    elif a != b and b == c or b !=c and c == a or c != a and a == b:
    """ Comparação a, b e c.
        Novamente o mesmo problema com a variável c.
    """
        print ('Isósceles')
    return
```

O mesmo problema vai se repetir na sua função angulo_class(), porém com outras variáveis. Recomendo sempre ter conhecimento do retorno de todas as suas variáveis, mesmo que seja só para teste.

Para corrigir esse problema você tem duas opções: Ajuste as suas comparações ou modifique suas funções.

```
# Opção 1. Ajuste dos condicionais.
if a != b and a != lado_c() and b != lado_c():
    (...)

# Opção 2. Ajuste das funções.
def lado_c ():
    """ Arredonde a variável c, e não apenas o retorno da função. 
        NOTA: Lembre-se que arredondar c irá influenciar
        os próximos cálculos que o utilizarem.
    """
    global a,b,c,ab
    c = round(math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b*math.cos(ab)))   
    return c
```

Em relação à **pergunta 2**: O *None* é o retorno vazio da função que decorre da própria forma que você escreveu as suas funções. Vou trabalhar com apenas uma delas, mas o raciocínio é o mesmo para ambas.

```
def lado_class():
    global a,b,c,ab
    if a != b and a != c and b != c:
        print ('Escaleno')
    elif ab == 60 and a == b and b == c:
        print ('Equilátero')
    elif a != b and b == c or b != c and c == a or c != a and a == b:
        print ('Isósceles')
    return    # <----- Essa é a linha que está definindo o retorno vazio.
```

Você tem a duas opções para corrigir isso. A primeira é de mudar o retorno de sua função para:

```
def lado_class():
    global a,b,c,ab
    if a != b and a != c and b != c:
        return 'Escaleno'     # Nesse caso o retorno será 'Escaleno'.
    elif ab == 60 and a == b and b == c:
        return 'Equilátero'   # Nesse caso o retorno será 'Equilátero'.
    elif a != b and b == c or b != c and c == a or c != a and a == b:
        return 'Isósceles'    # E finalmente aqui o retorno será 'Isósceles'.
```

Escrita dessa forma a função não dará o print quando usada e sim apenas retornará o valor indicado. Nesse caso, se quiser dar um print no retorno da função você escreverá:

```
print(lado_class())
```

Se você não quiser modificar sua função você pode usá-la sozinha. Sem a necessidade do print:

```
angulo_class()
```

Assim você não imprimirá o retorno *None* da sua função. Como você já programou o print dentro da função, não há a necessidade de dar um print no retorno dela.

Em resumo: Ao definir uma função atente-se a quando usar return e print. ([doc. return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt); [doc. print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print))

**Questão 4:** Eu colocaria tudo dentro de um while, mas não sei se é a forma mais indicada de se fazer isso. O while roda seu script até que você dê a condição para ele parar ([doc. while](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)).

Exemplo com while:

```
import math

repetir = True

while repetir is True:

    ##### Seu script aqui #####

    consulta_repet = input('Deseja repetir? (S/N)')
    comando_ok = False

    while comando_ok is False:
        if consulta_repet.lower() == 's':
            repetir = True
            comando_ok = True
        elif consulta_repet.lower() == 'n':
            repetir = False
            comando_ok = True
        else:
            consulta_repet = input('Comando não entendido. Deseja repetir? (S/N)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo. Este código irá **receber as medidas dos três lados do triângulo em uma mesma linha separados por apenas um espaço**, em seguida o programa irá verificar se as medidas dos lados formam de fato um triângulo e, se de fato formarem um triângulo, retornará o tipo do triângulo.

O código é o seguinte...

```
continuar = True
while continuar == True:
    try:
        l = list(map(float, input('Medida dos lados: ').split()))
        l.sort(reverse=True)
        print()

        if l[0] >= (l[1] + l[2]):
            print('NAO FORMA TRIANGULO')
        else:
            if (l[0] ** 2) == (l[1] ** 2 + l[2] ** 2):
                print('TRIANGULO RETANGULO')
            if (l[0] ** 2) > (l[1] ** 2 + l[2] ** 2):
                print('TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO')
            if (l[0] ** 2) < (l[1] ** 2 + l[2] ** 2):
                print('TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO')
            if l[0] == l[1] == l[2]:
                print('TRIANGULO EQUILATERO')
            if l[0] == l[1] != l[2] or l[1] == l[2] != l[0] or l[0] == l[2] != l[1]:
                print('TRIANGULO ISOSCELES')

        resposta = input('Digite "S" para reiniciar ou "N" para encerrar: ')
        while resposta not in 'SsNn':
            print(f'Valor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas uma das duas letras sugeridas!')
            resposta = input('Digite "S" para reiniciar ou "N" para encerrar: ')
        if resposta == 's' or resposta == 'S':
            continuar = True
        else:
            break

    except:
        break
```

Como você pode notar, este algoritmo não precisa saber as medidas dos ângulo para os identifica-los. Ele os identifica analisando apenas o comportamento do maior lado em relação aos outros.

Para você utilizar corretamente este programa, basta rodar o programa e digitar as medidas dos lados na mesma linha, separados por um espaço, tal qual mostrado abaixo...

```
Medida dos lados: 3 4 5
```

... em seguida, digitar "Enter" e o programa resolverá a situação exibindo o seguinte resultado...

```
TRIANGULO RETANGULO
Digite "S" para reiniciar ou "N" para encerrar:
```

... e então, você pode digitar "S" ou "N", de acordo com a situação.